# single Android SDK used by all the developers

Tags: android

To developer Android application we need to configure Android SDK either in Eclipse or in Android Studio.

I want to copy Android SDK in shared memory(hard disk) so everyone configures there eclipse or Android Studio from this place.

So when I will update Android SDK then it will reflect to all the developers.

If we update SDK to each developer system then it will consume lots  of data.

That's why I want to maintain one global Android SDK which will use by everyone.

Is this possible, or is there any way to do this?

Comment: This is a general question about software. What you want is to make a locale network integration. I guess you should ask here: http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Yes.  Make a docker image

Comment: Do not use eclipse.